# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function selectAll() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was following a tutorial on laracasts.com, my PDO connection was working fine, but after some refactoring im getting the following error 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function selectAll() on null'.

Here's my code

index.php

```
<?php

$query = require 'bootstrap.php';

require 'Task.php';

$tasks = $query->selectAll('todos');

require 'index.view.php';
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

require 'database/Connection.php';
require 'database/QueryBuilder.php';

return new QueryBuilder(Connection::make());
```

Connection.php

```
<?php

class Connection

{
public static function make()
{
    try {

        return new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mytodo', 'root', '');

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

QueryBuilder.php

```
<?php

class QueryBuilder
{

protected $pdo;

public function __contruct($pdo)
{
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}


  public function selectAll($table)
  {
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("select * from {$table}");

    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
  }

}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$query = require 'bootstrap.php';` what?!

Comment: Its just a file that requires 2 other files.

Comment: JFYI: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)